# how update/render <for:forEach with ajax

Tags: jsf

I got a list with steps which I displays as follow:

```
<ul >
    <for:forEach id="steps" items="#{RecipeBean.recipe.steps}" var="step">
        <li>  <com:Step description="#{step.stepDescription}"/></li>
    </for:forEach>
</ul>
<p:commandButton id="addstep" value="#{msg['step.add']}" action="#{RecipeBean.addStep}" update="steps" />
```

The button addStep adds a Step to the RecipeBean.recipe.steps collection. Now the new added step should be displayed. But like that I get the error message Cannot find component with identifier "steps" referenced from "j_idt8:addstep" and this is probably of the for:forEach component.

So does someone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Why did you gave the JSTL core library a namespace prefix of `for` instead of `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `update` attribute of the `<p:commandButton>` component should point to a component. Since `<for:forEach>` is not a component, but a taghandler, you receive an error message.

I would suggest you take a look at the existing PrimeFaces components like [DataList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dataListUnordered.jsf), which presents a list objects in unordered format.

Then, you can refactor your code as follows:

```
<p:dataList id="steps" items="#{RecipeBean.recipe.steps}" 
            var="step" itemType="disc">
    <com:Step description="#{step.stepDescription}" />
</p:dataList>
<p:commandButton id="addstep" value="#{msg['step.add']}" 
                 action="#{RecipeBean.addStep}" update="steps" />
```

Comment: The use of <p:dataList make sense. Thanks. But for some reason I get with "                <p:dataList id="steps" value="#{RecipeBean.recipe.steps}" var="step" itemType="disc">
                    <com:Step description="#{step.stepDescription}" />
                </p:dataList>" a Stackoverflow Exception. For testing reasons I add in the RecipeBean in the init() PostConstruct some Steps for the Recipe propertie.